# Using plugins SDK in Liferay DXP

Tags: eclipse, liferay, liferay-dxp, liferay-blade-cli

I am trying to get my liferay workspace to work using blade CLI but am having difficulties.

I followed this article from the official liferay developer website:
https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/creating-a-liferay-workspace-with-blade-cli

There it says: '*See the [Using a Plugins SDK From Your Workspace](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/creating-a-liferay-workspace#using-a-plugins-sdk-from-your-workspace) section for more information on how to use a Plugins SDK from within a workspace*.'

When I clicked the link I was redirected to a page stating '*The article you requested was not found*' and now I am stuck and can't find information anywhere.

Does anyone have an idea of what I have to do at this point?

Another problem is, that the installer is downloading the community edition of liferay instead of the enterprise edition when running `gradlew.bat initBundle` or `gradlew.bat distBundleTar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liferay DXP uses a module-based framework. They encourages us to go that way, though you could use the former Plugins SDK too, as it's still supported. Have a look at https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/liferay-workspace for details.

Blade CLI provides you with some templates to create new projects following the new framework.

I'd go modular.

Regards

Comment: thanks for answering. my problem is, that when following the instructions on the linked page, I can't get past 'gradlew initBundle', because it tries to download the CE edition of liferay but I want to use my (already downloaded) EE sdk instead. Do you know how to tell gradle which bundle to choose? I tried setting liferay.workspace.bundle.url to nothing and pointed liferay.workspace.plugins.sdk.dir to my sdk but it did not work, the ce-edition is still getting downloaded...

Comment: Not sure if you're mixing concepts like Liferay bundle and SDK. If you go modular you dont need an SDK. 

Download a Liferay bundle (a server), in case you haven't already and set your Liferay Home in gradle.properties:
`liferay.workspace.home.dir=[PATH_TO_YOUR_BUNDLE]`

No need to set sdk.dir

Comment: is [PATH_TO_YOUR_BUNDLE] the packed version (tar|zip) or the path to the liferay portal dir? and do I have to do `gradlew.bat initBundle` after that?

Comment: It's the path to the unpacked bundle, usually known as Liferay_home. Inside you should find your tomcat (if it's a tomcat bundle). You have to create a Liferay workspace (I guess you have that already), and after setting your liferay.workspace.home.dir, call gradle initBundle, indeed. Maybe it's a good idea starting with the help of Liferay IDE, where those tasks are done automatically.

Comment: when I run gradle initBundle a download of liferay ce gets started. do you have any idea why? output: `Download https://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20Portal/7.0.1%20GA2/liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.0-ga2-20160610113014153.zip`

Comment: Yep. You're right. My bad. InitBundle downloads the bundle version you have set in your gradle.properties. You don't need to call it, as you have your own EE bundle.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of running initBundle, you can create a Liferay workspace using blade init command. Once the workspace is created, you can create module projects on it using blade create. For an extensive list of blade commands to efficiently use this tool, you can refer to the following link:

https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/blade-cli

The Liferay developer network site was under development back then but now it is updated for further references.